# Should we only use Web-Safe Colors while in design/coding/development for website/apps?

Tags: css, xhtml, colors

Should we only use Web-Safe Colors while in design/coding/development for website/apps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. This is a non issue, just about any computer made in the last 5 years can handle any combinations of RGB/hex colors without any problems. The guidelines you're referring to were intended to compensate for older displays/browsers that couldn't render the full spectrum of colors available via CSS.

Comment: try the last 10 years, at least. web safe colours are from a time when 256 colour displays were still common. I can't even think of a modern PDA that suffers such limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Web Safe colors are meant for Cathode Ray Tube (CRT) based Devices. But from the last 7-8 years, LCDs and LEDs are popular. So now we can use non web safe colors. There were only 216 colors in web safe or True web colors. Now a days, only projectors are of low resolution, even smart phones and tablets are HD or FHD.

Answer (score 0):

If using plain colors makes your work with designing, coding and developing easier, then I say go for it. However, if you are doing it because you think there is some other benefit to doing so, I say stop. There is no need to use web safe colors unless you are designing for users that are color blind or using assistive devices.

For the vast majority of devices you should avoid web safe colors as they look amateurish and distract the viewer from your message or from looking at your images. More important is legibility of your text which derives from good contrast and color shades with enough gap to make body text, link text, and headers legible.